# In Visual Studio, how do I add the "Insert / Delete Breakpoint" command to a toolbar or menu?

Tags: visual-studio, toolbar, breakpoints

I'd like to add the command for inserting/deleting a breakpoint to a toolbar in VS.  This command is available, for example, by right-clicking on an area in the code editor window and selecting "*Breakpoint | Insert Breakpoint*":

[image]

I can't find where the command is.  I've searched through all the "Categories", and I particularly thought it would be in the "*Debug*" category where other breakpoint commands reside:

[image]

Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the "*Toggle Breakpoint*" command in the "Debug" category:

[image]

This creates a text-only button like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, the button is text-only -- no icon -- and always says "Toggle..." unlike the similar command mentioned in the OP that is accessible from the context menu in the code window which has an icon and changes from "Insert..." to "Delete..." depending on the context.

[image]